# Visual Studio External Tools sending command to command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extensibility

I added Run IL button to external tool section of visual studio .
[image]

when this button triggered i want to compile current file with ilasm.I can open developer command prompt in this way,however i couldn't add file directory so i have to write "ilasm program.il" all the time 
[image]

How can it be done automatically ?
[image]

Comment: Do you need to run this only when you build the solution?

Comment: Could you just use a batch file?

Comment: Yeah i tried and failed.Developer Command Prompt is using a bat file for compile the (ms)il code.But i couldn't figure out how's working.

Comment: You should post the code that you tried already, maybe someone will be able to help with what is going wrong

Comment: Thanks Bassie,i solved this problem with batch file :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ilasm.exe"  %1


SETLOCAL
set file=%1
FOR %%i IN (%file%) DO (
set filedrive=%%~di
set filepath=%%~pi
set filename=%%~ni
set fileextension=%%~xi
)

start %filedrive%%filepath%%filename%.exe


pause
```

I writed a bat file then i edit my external tool like this 
 [image]

Also i added shortcut.

[image]

Now this is working perfect :)